# html2canvas Error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: html2canvas

I have used the below code to generate the screenshot of a grid in my page. The 'gridBody' in the code below is a DOM object.

```
html2canvas(gridBody ,{
                   onrendered:function(canvas){
                      var img = canvas.toDataURL();
                      window.open(img);
                   }
                });
```

But it gives an error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (html2canvas.js:2191)
_html2canvas.Preload (html2canvas.js:2191)
(anonymous function)

line 2191 in html2canvas.js file:

```
domImages = element.getElementsByTagName('img'), // Fetch images of the present element only
```

This works absolutely fine when i give 'document.body' instead of 'gridBody'.

Can you please help me out, why is the error coming?

Note: gridBody DOM starts and ends with

```
<div>
```

tags. I can share it, but this space doesnt allow to paste the entire DOM here, and i dont see any way to attach a file.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and found that it was due to the selector that was passed in to html2canvas being empty. This resulted in 'element' not being an element.